# Find variables and the dependencies between them in code

Tags: matlab, variables, dependencies

I am trying to write a function that finds all the variables in a function which contains computing operations. I do this to find out which variables this block of calculations requires as input arguments to perform the calculations.

A calculation function always gets a table with different parameters as input, accesses certain parameters of that table to calculate certain metrics.

For example my data table `T` contains the double arrays `Power` and `Time`. This table is passed to the function `calc_energy` which then calculates `Energy`:

```
function [ T ] = calc_energy( T )
T.Energy = T.Power .* T.Time;
end
```

Say whenever a new data table is generated, different calculations as the above one are run automatically. Now if `Power` itself is calculated by the function `calc_power`, but `calc_energy` is run before or parallel to `calc_power`, then I have a problem because `calc_energy` doesn't find the required variables in `T`.

In order to prevent such an error, I want my function `check_required_variables` to be called inside the `calc_energy` and check beforehand whether `T.Power` exists. The thing is that `check_required_variables` should be a general function that is called in every single calculation function and therefore doesn't know the required variables. It has to find them in the function that it is called by.

```
function [ T ] = calc_energy( T )
OK = check_required_variables( T, 'calc_energy.m' );
if OK == 1
    T.Energy = T.Power .* T.Time;
else
    error('Required fields not found');
end
end
```

Are there any functions that spot the variables `Energy`, `Power` and `Time` used in my code? And are there functions that maybe analyse the dependencies between these variables (`Energy` dependent on `Power` and `Time`)? What are generally clever ways to figure out the ocurring variables just from the code? Any ideas?

I know this is a tough one so I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: @rahnema1: Please see my edited questions in the second to last paragraph. I tried to connect them better to the depicted problem.

Comment: Doesn't the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324123/6579744) provided by @AnderBiguri solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `isfield`

```
function [ T ] = calc_energy( T )
if all(isfield(T,{'Power','Time'}))
    T.Energy = T.Power .* T.Time;
else
    error('Nooooope')
end
end
```

However, knowing which ones are required seems a bit harder.... You can always try to read the `.m` file, and regexp for `T.____`, then put the input of that to `isfield`.

This however, just hints of bad software design. A function *should know* what it requires to run. What happens if OK is false? It just skips the computation? You can then cascade to hundreds of calls (depend on the application) because the original structure failed to have a variable, or had a typo. I'd take the radically opposite approach to software design:

```
function [ T ] = calc_energy( T )

assert(all(isfield(T,{'Power','Time'}))); %error if there are not.

T.Energy = T.Power .* T.Time;    
end
```

Comment: Thanks! "isfield" might be a very useful function. And thanks for the hint to regexp. I already thought about just scanning the whole code, but I thought that, since MATLAB is able to recognise all the in the code variables, there might be a function that spots the variables and returns a list of their names for example. Maybe MATLAB is even able to trace back `Energy` to `Power` and `Time`.

Comment: @JonasB let me repeat just in case: **this is a terrible way of designing code**.

Comment: Looking for ways to solve my problem, I've come across "mlint", MATLAB's linting tool. It provides very useful functions, as for example listing all the functions called in a .m-file. Also it is able to recognize undefined variables (at least those which are declared in that .m-file). So obviously MATLAB recognizes every variable name. Is there also a way to make mlint return all the variable names (since `T.Power` and `T.Time` aren't declared in my function)?

Comment: @JonasB I don't know, really, never used it. However, it is not easily doable **because it is a terrible idea**. I really suggest you have a though of why you are doing this and think about other better ways of doing this. Think, if this was a good idea, why is MATLAB (or any other interpreted programming language) not doing it yet?

Comment: I can see why it seems to you as if there had to be an entirely different approach to overcome my problem, as rethinking the whole idea. The reason why I still want to do exactly what I asked for, is that I am creating a framework for sub-classes (as `calc_energy`) that are created by users. My superclass helps manage all these sub-classes and contains the method `check_required_variables`. Since I 
want to give my users as much freedom as possible, `check_required_variables` is supposed to recognize the used variables on its own.

Comment: Thanks @Ander for putting up with my stubbornness. I start seeing more clearly now that having a function analyse code is neither the nice the best nor the easiest way. I go with a different approach then. Obviously needed to learn this lesson the hard way ;)